# How to close a frmStartup modeless winform after Application.Run(new MainWinForm())

Tags: c#

How to close the frmStartup modeless winform after MainWinform loaded in Application.Run(new MainWinForm()). If simply put frmStartup.Close() after Application.Run(new MainWinForm()) it doesn't work.

```
static void Main()
    {
    .....
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Startup frmStartup = new Startup();
        frmStartup.Show();
        frmStartup.TopMost = true;
        frmStartup.Update();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        frmStartup.Close();

        Application.Run(new MainWinForm());
    }
```

Comment: The form cannot be responsive (paint itself or respond to input) unless you called Application.Run() or its ShowDialog() method.  ShowDialog() being the more obvious way to do it, give it a Timer so it closes itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : pass frmStartup into MainWinForm by constructor

Example :

Program.cs

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
            // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();

            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1.Show();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Application.Run(new Form2(form1));
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 _form1;

        public Form2(Form1 form1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _form1 = form1;
        }

        private void Form2_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_form1 != null)
            {
                _form1.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```